# Rails: Auto-reload gem files used in dummy app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

When developing a gem, I often use a dummy rails app that requires the gem in order to try out gem changes as I go. Also, I use the same dummy app for integration tests.

Usually, I have the gem in

```
~/rails/foo_gem
```

and the associated dummy app in:

```
~/rails/foo_gem/spec/dummy_app
```

With the [zeitwerk](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) code loader, **how do I configure the dummy app** to not only reload dummy-app ruby files on change, but also **to pick up the changes to the gem files**? Otherwise, I would have to reload the dummy-app rails server for every change to the gem files while developing the gem.

```rb
# ~/rails/foo_gem/spec/dummy_app/config/environments/development.rb

config.cache_classes = false
config.eager_load = false

# TODO: Add ~/rails/foo_gem/lib to the list 
# of watched and auto-reloaded directories.
```

### Did not work: `config.autoload_paths`

```rb
# ~/rails/foo_gem/spec/dummy_app/config/environments/development.rb

gem_root_path = Pathname.new(File.expand_path(Rails.root.join("../..")))
config.autoload_paths << gem_root_path.join("lib")
```

I've tried to add the gem to the autoload paths, but the code is not reloaded on file-system changes.

### Did not work: `Zeitwerk::Loader` with `enable_reloading`

```rb
# ~/rails/foo_gem/spec/dummy_app/config/environments/development.rb

gem_root_path = Pathname.new(File.expand_path(Rails.root.join("../..")))
gem_loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.new
gem_loader.push_dir gem_root_path.join("lib")
gem_loader.enable_reloading
gem_loader.log!
gem_loader.setup
```

Adding a separate zeitwerk loader does not help; the loader does not come with a file-system watcher as far as I have understood it; so one needs to call `gem_loader.reload` in order to reload the gem classes.

### Did not work: `Zeitwerk::Loader#reload` with `require`

If the gem's files are required within the gem, e.g.

```rb
# ~/rails/foo_gem/lib/foo_gem.rb

require 'foo_gem/bar`
```

then the file `~/rails/foo_gem/lib/foo_gem/bar.rb` is ignored by the `Zeitwerk::Loader`. Calling `gem_loader.reload` does not reload this file.

### Did not work: `Zeitwerk::Loader#reload` with zeitwerk loader for gem files

If the gem's files are not required manually, but instead a different zeitwerk loader is used, e.g.

```rb
# ~/rails/foo_gem/lib/foo_gem.rb

require "zeitwerk"
loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.new
loader.push_dir(__dir__)
loader.setup
```

then the directory `~/rails/foo_gem/lib` is managed by two separate zeitwerk loaders: the `loader` in `foo_gem.rb` and the `gem_loader` in `development.rb`. This is apparently not allowed by zeitwerk, which complains with a `Zeitwerk::Error`:

> loader ... wants to manage directory ~/rails/foo_gem/lib, which is already managed by ...

### Did not work: `ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker`

```rb
# ~/rails/foo_gem/spec/dummy_app/config/environments/development.rb

gem_root_path = Pathname.new(File.expand_path(Rails.root.join("../..")))
gem_loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.new
gem_loader.push_dir gem_root_path.join("lib")
gem_loader.enable_reloading
gem_loader.log!
gem_loader.setup

gem_files = gem_root_path.glob("lib/**/*.rb")
gem_update_checker = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker.new(gem_files) do
  gem_loader.reload  # This line is never executed
end
ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_prepare do
  gem_update_checker.execute_if_updated
end
```

I've tried to use the [`ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/FileUpdateChecker.html) to watch for changes, but, at least with my dockerized setup, the block to reload the code is never executed.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to to the same thing, and found your answer, as well as https://stackoverflow.com/a/66730720/373254. I've not tried yet, but if it works, it seems a bit simpler than yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reload the gem code on file-system changes, I needed to do three steps:

1. Unregister the zeitwerk loader defined in `foo_gem.rb` that handles loading the different gem files.
2. Define a new zeitwerk loader in the `development.rb` of the dummy app that is configured with `enable_reloading`.
3. Setup a file-system watcher and trigger a reload when a gem file changes.

I'm sure there is a simpler and cleaner solution. Feel free to post it as a separate answer. I'll post my solution here, but do consider it a workaround.

### `Zeitwerk::Loader` in `foo_gem.rb`

```rb
# ~/rails/foo_gem/lib/foo_gem.rb

# require 'foo_gem/bar`  # Did not work. Instead:

# (a) use zeitwerk:
require "zeitwerk"
loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.new
loader.push_dir File.join(__dir__)
loader.tag = "foo_gem"
loader.setup

# or (b) use autoload:
module FooGem
  autoload :Bar, "foo_gem/bar"
end
```

Note:

- In the past, I've just loaded all ruby files of the gem with `require` from a kind of index file called just like the gem, here: `foo_gem.rb`. This does not work here, because zeitwerk appears to ignore files that have previously been loaded with `require`. Instead I needed to create a separate zeitwerk loader for the gem.
- This loader has no `enable_reloading` because otherwise, reloading would be enabled for this gem whenever using the gem, not just while developing the gem.
- I have given the loader a `tag`, which allows to find this loader later in the `Zeitwerk::Registry` in order to un-register it.
- Instead of using zeitwerk in `foo_gem.rb`, one could also use `autoload` there [like the devise gem does](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise.rb). This is the best way if one wants to support rails versions earlier than 6 because zeitwerk requires rails 6+. Using `autoload` here also makes step 1 in the next section unnecessary.

### Zeitwerk::Loader in `development.rb` of the dummy app

```rb
# ~/rails/foo_gem/spec/dummy_app/config/environments/development.rb

# 1. Unregister the zeitwerk loader defined in foo_gem.rb that handles loading
#    the different gem files.
#
Zeitwerk::Registry.loaders.detect { |l| l.tag == "foo_gem" }.unregister

# 2. Define a new zeitwerk loader in the development.rb of the dummy app
#    that is configured with enable_reloading.
#
gem_root_path = Pathname.new(File.expand_path(Rails.root.join("../..")))
gem_loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.new
gem_loader.push_dir gem_root_path.join("lib")
gem_loader.enable_reloading
gem_loader.setup

# 3. Setup a file-system watcher and trigger a reload when a gem file changes.
#
Listen.to gem_root_path.join("lib"), only: /\.rb$/ do
  gem_loader.reload
end.start
```

Note:

- Zeitwerk does not allow two loaders managing the same files. Therefore, I need to unregister the previously defined loader tagged `"foo_gem"`.
- The new loader used in the dummy app has `enable_reloading`. Therefore, when using the dummy app with `rails server`, `rails console`, or when running the specs, the gem files can be reloaded.
- The gem files are not automatically reloaded by zeitwerk. One needs a file-system watcher to trigger the reload on file-system changes. I did not manage to get the [`ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/FileUpdateChecker.html) working. Instead, I've used the [listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) gem as file-system watcher.

With this setup, when using the `rails server`, the `rails console` of the dummy app or integration tests using the dummy app, gem files are reloaded after being edited, which means that one does no longer need to restart the `rails server` to pick up the changes.

### References

- [`Zeitwerk::Loader`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/zeitwerk/Zeitwerk/Loader)
- [`Zeitwerk::Registry`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/zeitwerk/Zeitwerk/Registry)
- https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Answer (score 0):

Auto reloading with Zeitwerk should just work if you run your Rails server in the root of your engine, instead of in the /test/dummy directory, like so:

```
# This:
/Users/lewis/work/myengine $ rails server

# NOT this:
/Users/lewis/work/myengine/test/dummy $ rails server

# NOT this:
/Users/lewis/work/myengine $ test/dummy/bin/rails server
```